# Alguém pode me ajudar pra quando dar else:print("Desculpe mas não existe esta opção"), ele recomeçar o programa?

Tags: python

```
print("--- Calcular Queda Livre ---")`insira o código aqui`
    opcao=int(input("""Digite:
1 para Função Horária da posição;
2 para Função Horária da velocidade;
3 para Equação de Torricelli;
4 para Velocidade média da queda;
Escolha: """))
if opcao==1:
    print("""
--- Função Horária da Posição ---
""")
    g=float(input("Digite a Gravidade(g): "))
    t=float(input("Digite o Tempo: "))
    h=(g*t)/2
    print(f"""
Resultado: {h}
""")
elif opcao==2:
    print("""
--- Função Horária da Velocidade ---
""")
    g=float(input("Digite a Gravidade(g): "))
    t=float(input("Digite o Tempo: "))
    v=g*t
    print(f"""
Resultado: {v}
""")
elif opcao==3:
    print("""
--- Equação Torricelli ---
""")
    g=float(input("Digite a gravidade(g): "))
    Δh=float(input("Digite a altura(Δh): "))
    v2=2*g*Δh
    print(f"""
Resultado: {v2}
""")
elif opcao==4:
    print("""
--- Velocidade Média da Queda ---
""")
    v0=float(input("Digite a velocidade da queda: "))
    v=float(input("Digite a velocidade final: "))
    Vm=(v+v0)/2
    print(f"""
Resultado: {Vm}
""")

else:
    print("Desculpe mas não existe esta opção")
```

Comment: Coloca seu código dentro de um laço de repetição. Se a ideia é repetir, nada melhor que um laço de repetição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onde está `opcao=int(input(...` coloque `while (True):` antes. Fica assim:

```
while (True):
    opcao=int(input(...
```

Você pode adicionar mais uma opção para sair do laço. Fica assim:

```
while (True):
    opcao=int(input(...

    if opcao==1:...
    elif opcao==2:
    elif opcao==3:
    elif opcao==4:
    elif opcao==5: break
    else: print("Desculpe mas não existe esta opção")
```

*Não se esqueça que o Python usa a indentação para delimitar os blocos.*